# How can I correctly display Chinese characters on Debian 5?

Tags: debian, fonts, qt

When I try to use Chinese chars on a QT application, my pc shows rectangles instead of Chinese characters. My old system is version Debian 5 , I can use Chinese chars in Debian 8. I use the same font in both versions.  How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Debian 5 (and 6) are past end-of-life (an upgrade is overdue).

Comment: @ThomasDickey just slightly :)

Comment: Install unifont.

Comment: Installing **fonts-wqy-zenhei** font package solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed **fonts-wqy-zenhei** font package and it solved my issue.